# how to update a value without adding it as a child to a scene

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, cocos2d-iphone

so i am trying to update the score in my game, and the code is running fine but the structure doesnt seem right to me. what I am doing right now is keeping the score in a var and then removing the old child and adding a new child to update the score, something like :

```
if([self awake]){
    int score = (int) x;
    //NSLog(@"%i", score);

    CCLabelBMFont * scoreLabel = [CCLabelBMFont labelWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Score : %d", score] fntFile:@"good_dog_plain_32.fnt"];
    scoreLabel.position = ccp(100, 300);
    [scoreScene addChild:scoreLabel];

        if([_game getChildByTag:123]){
            [_game removeChildByTag:123 cleanup:YES];
        }
    [_game addChild:scoreScene z:99 tag:123];
}
```

now this code works just fine but its ruining the fps for the game!!! is there anyway I can update the value of scoreLabel without having to remove and then add the score to the main scene of the game?

thanks

**UPDATED CODE**
final fixed code :

in the main layer of the game I added

```
CCLabelBMFont * scoreLabel;
```

in the header file.

in the main init of the game I added

```
int score = 0;
        scoreLabel = [CCLabelBMFont labelWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Score : %d", score] fntFile:@"good_dog_plain_32.fnt"];

        CCScene * scoreScene = [CCScene node];
        scoreLabel.position = ccp(100, 300);
        [scoreScene addChild:scoreLabel];
        [self addChild:scoreScene z:99 tag:123];
```

and then simply used setString in my method to update the score like :

```
 [_game.scoreLabel setString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Score : %d", score]];
```

note that `_game` is because I declared the scoreLabel in the main scene, and my method is running in another file, so if you have your highscore method in the same file, there is no need for `_game`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CCLabelBMFont implement the [CCLabelProtocol](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/0.99.5/protocol_c_c_label_protocol-p.html), so it's respond to the setString: method.

You just have to had your "scoreLabel" in the init method and then update the score like that:

```
if([self awake])
{
    int score = (int) x;
    //NSLog(@"%i", score);

    [scoreLabel setString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Score : %d", score]];
}
```

**EDIT**

It can looks like that:

```
- (id)init
{
   if ((self = [super init]))
   {
      self.score = 0;

      CCLabelBMFont *scoreLabel = [CCLabelBMFont labelWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Score : %d", score] fntFile:@"good_dog_plain_32.fnt"];
      scoreLabel.position = ccp(100, 300);
      [self addChild:scoreLabel z:1 tag:123];
   }
}

- (void)updateScore
{
   CCLabelBMFont *scorelabel = (CCLabelBMFont *)[self getChildByTag:123];
   [scorelabel setString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Score: %d",self.score]];
}
```

Comment: so i need to add the scoreLabel to the game scene once and then use setString to update it right?

Comment: listen I just posted a new updated code in the question from what I thought you meant to say, can you tell me if its right, because I tried it and it doesnt update the code!

Comment: Yes, add the label to the scene into your init method. Then you just have to retrieve it by keeping a reference, or using its tag ([_game getChildByTag:123]). To finish call the setString on the label.

Comment: EDIT: You have to create your Label into the init, not into your method. Because here you create a new label each time you call the method.

Comment: ok thanks alot :) it works now, does it affect the performance alot if I use CCLabelBMFont with a font? because Im getting a better fps, but its still not that good...

Comment: You should be careful when you update the label. Update it only when it's needed (Here for example, only when the score changed, not each frame). On the Cocos2d forum they tell that the best choice: http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/16278.

Comment: thanks for the link it was helpful, just one last question, the game is a physics game, and its technically an object moving and the highscore for now is the distance that the ball passes so the score needs to be updated constantly, is there any way I can do this more efficiently ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know how you could improve the fps with the CCLabelBMFont. :! You could take a look there, there are some tips to improve the performance with Cocos2d: http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/prog_guide:best_practices#creating_nodes_ccsprite_cclabel_etc

Answer (score 0):

Use CCLabelAtlas instead and use setString to change the string of the CCLabelAtlas object.